# Grabbing mysql dump file from remote server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mysql

Im working as an intern and am new to rails and it's production evn. I was wondering how I could grab a database dump from a remote server and import into my local database so that my local env mirrors that of the live version of a site. I have access to the database, and I have the current version of the code in my environment. I am missing the pictures and files attached to the site, and need it to make changes locally.

Answer (score 7):

1. In the production server execute the following command

   mysqldump -u username -ppassword db_name > production_dump.sql
2. scp the production_dump.sql file to your local machine
3. In your local machine execute the following command.

   mysql -u username -ppassword db_name < production_dump.sql